# InitializeComponent code is being generated in base cs file, not designer file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a c# solution that i wrote some years ago. We need to change the client area of the form, so I make the necessary changes in the designer. When saved or built, i get an error: `Type 'frmMobileBase' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types`
When I look...there it is...in the main frmMobileBase.cs file, not the frmMobileBase.Designer.cs.
Below is a screen shot of the files...they are all separated:

[image]

as you can see, there's the frmMobileBase.cs file, that has the full class tree below it,
and there is a frmMobileBase.designer.cs with the same thing.

So the questions I have are:

- How can I modify the form and have the code go into the designer.cs file as it should?
- Why/how did this happen?
- Is there a permanent fix?

Comment: Old versions of VS insert the Dispose, InitializeComponent and all the control declaration directly in the CS file. The designer file has been introduced later. Is it possible that your form has been designed with a very older VS ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the old version problem. I had the same issue with forms, created in VS 10-15 years ago.